# How can I toggle the appearance of the *Compilation* buffer?

Tags: emacs, elisp, compilationmode

I've recently switched to using emacs.
One of the things that I want to be able to do is to toggle the appearance of the compilation buffer using `Ctrl+,` (i.e. when the compilation buffer is visible on the screen, I want to be able to press `Ctrl+,` to hide it, and then press `Ctrl+,` to bring it back up).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a function modified from [Spacemacs](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs):

```lisp
(defun toggle-compilation-window ()
  "Show/Hide the window containing the '*compilation*' buffer."
  (interactive)
  (when-let ((buffer compilation-last-buffer))
    (if (get-buffer-window buffer 'visible)
        (delete-windows-on buffer)
      (display-buffer buffer))))

(bind-key "C-," #'toggle-compilation-window)
```

I also suggest taking a look at this awesome package [popper](https://github.com/karthink/popper)